# How do I slice the list containing multiple variables in numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I need to Slice this list and need to separate (Altitude=170,180 etc) alone?

```
L=['"Altitude","height","Distance"','170,159,160','180,177,145']
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure about what you need, and the list looks weird. Convert into a data.frame and pull out the column?

```
import pandas as pd

L=['"Altitude","height","Distance"','170,159,160','180,177,145']

df = pd.DataFrame([i.split(",") for i in L[1:]],
    columns=L[0].replace('"',"").split(","))

df['Altitude']
Out[34]: 
0    170
1    180
```